# What am I doing wrong, Javascript card game, higher equal and lower?

Tags: javascript

I have a card game with three options 'higher' 'equal' and 'lower'. When you select and option and the outcome of your card is the option you chose (higher/euqal/lower to the computers card) a banner comes up saying 'you win'. This happens also if you choose the wrong outcome, 'you lose'. So far with the code I have the higher button is the only one carrying out the function I want. (When I chose higher, and my outcome is higher than the computers card I get told I win, also if I chose higher and my guess is wrong it says I lose).

The 'equal' button and 'lower' button do not carry out the function correctly. The banner pops up telling my I've won or lost, but it is not right and doesn't correspond with my chosen option and the cards outcome. For example: I chose lower, my card outcome is lower than the computers card, it tells me I've lost. I should tell me I've won here instead.

Here's part of my javascript:

```
 function Player(){

var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*13)+1;
total = total + 5;
document.getElementById('img2').src = y+'.gif';
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = total;

if(document.getElementById('higher').clicked == true && x < y)
{
    document.getElementById("win").style.display = "block";
} 
else (document.getElementById('higher').clicked == true && x > y)
{
    document.getElementById("lose").style.display = "block";
}

if(document.getElementById('equal').clicked == true && x == y)
{
    document.getElementById("win").style.display = "block";
} 
else (document.getElementById('equal').clicked == true && x != y)
{
    document.getElementById("lose").style.display = "block";
}

if(document.getElementById('lower').clicked == true && x > y)
{
    document.getElementById("win").style.display = "block";
} 
else (document.getElementById('lower').clicked == true && x < y)
{
    document.getElementById("lose").style.display = "block";
}

}
```

Comment: You should use `===` when comparing values to avoid type coercion

Comment: Why is Playerchoice Hardcoded?

Comment: Where are you getting which button the user clicked on?

Comment: should had some parenthesis in your if statements to make sure about the priority.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
var playerChoice = "higher";
```

Set that to what the player actually chose, instead of hardcoding `"higher"` in there.

Comment: Thank you, what should I put there instead of "higher", is there some code i can put there that will stand for what ever button was clicked by the player? Sorry, Im quite new to this, so still learning :)

Comment: That depends on the way you're triggering the `Player` function. You could pass a "choice" parameter to it, like: `onclick="Player('lower')"`, then pick up that parameter like this:   `function Player(playerChoice){`

Answer (score 0):

I have no Idea what u meant, so here is your game.

It is working, not perfectly, but should be enough

```js
function load(){
  document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*13)+1;
  document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("higher").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("equal").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("lower").style.visibility = "visible";      
}


function Player(object){
  var playerChoice = object.id;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*13)+1;
  var x = document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML;
  alert(playerChoice + " " + x + " " + y);
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = y;
  if  ((playerChoice === "higher") && (x < y) || 
   ( playerChoice === "lower") && (x > y) || 
   ( playerChoice === "equal") && (x == y)) 
   {
     document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = " is " + playerChoice + " than ";
   }
  else{
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = " is not " + playerChoice + " than ";
  }
  document.getElementById("lower").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("equal").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("higher").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<text id="test"></text>
<text id="test2"></text>
<text id="test3"></text>
<button onclick="Player(this)" id = "higher" style="visibility:hidden"> higher</button>
<button onclick="Player(this)" id = "equal" style="visibility:hidden"> equal</button>
<button onclick="Player(this)" id = "lower" style="visibility:hidden"> lower</button>
<button onclick="load()" id = "newGame"> New Game</button>
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `this`, use the event object passed to the function, instead. Also, don't use the `id` to get the choice, properly indent your code, and SO is English, so I'd suggest not using German in your code.

Comment: Edited as u commented, but still i like passing this, don't know why. I learned it that way ;)